# Find even numbers in an array using pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to find the even numbers in the array `arr[100];` using pointers.

```
int main()
{

    int ar[100],*i,*j,n=0,even,*peven=&even;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=ar;i<ar+n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",ar+n);
    }
    for(i=ar;i<ar+n;i++)
    {
        *peven=0;
        for(j=ar;j<ar+n;j++)
        {
            if((*ar+n)%2==0)
            {
                (*peven)++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d",*peven);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post sample input, and expected output.

Comment: I suggest looping through your arrays based on an index into the array. Something like `for(int index=0; index<n; index++){ scanf("%d", &ar[index]); }`

Comment: Because of operator precedence `if((*ar+n)%2==0)` should be `if(*(ar+n)%2==0)`.  That's assuming you have a reason to use pointer arithmetic instead of subscripting for some reason (maybe it's an assignment requirement?).

Answer (score 0):

`ar+n` is a pointer to `arr[n]`. That's correct for the limit of your `for` loops, but you shouldn't be using it inside the loop bodies. In the loops, `i` is the pointer to the current element of the array.

There's also no reason for nested loops when finding the even elements.

```
for(i=ar;i<ar+n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",i);
}
*peven = 0;
for(i=ar;i<ar+n;i++)
{
    if (*i % 2 == 0)
    {
        (*peven)++;
    }
}
printf("%d",*peven);
```